# iterate through nested hashes using conditionals in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to build a new_hash from this hash:

```
languages = {
  :oo => {
    :ruby => {
      :type => "interpreted"
    },
    :javascript => {
      :type => "interpreted"
    },
    :python => {
      :type => "interpreted"
    }  
  },
  :functional => {
    :clojure => {
      :type => "compiled"
    },
    :erlang => {
      :type => "compiled"
    },
    :javascript => {
      :type => "interpreted"
    } 
  }
}
```

and the desired result is:

```
{
  :ruby => {
    :type => "interpreted",
    :style => [:oo]
  },
  :javascript => {
    :type => "interpreted",
    :style => [:oo, :functional]
  },
  :python => {
    :type => "interpreted",
    :style => [:oo]
  },
  :clojure => {
    :type => "compiled",
    :style => [:functional]
  },
  :erlang => {
    :type => "compiled",
    :style => [:functional]
  }  
}
```

Here is what I've done so far:

```
def reformat_languages(languages)
  new_hash = {}
  languages.each do |k, v|
    v.each do |k1, v1|
      new_hash[k1] = v1
      new_hash[k1][:style] = []
      new_hash[k1][:style] << k     
    end
  end
  new_hash
end
```

unfortunately, I cannot get the desired result. I understand that when the iteration arrives at the second javascript key, it re-writes over the first iteration giving me:

```
 :javascript => {
    :type => "interpreted",
    :style => [:functional]
  }
```

instead of:

```
:javascript => {
    :type => "interpreted",
    :style => [:oo, :functional]
  }
```

Here is a link of a repl.it where I you can see the code in action: https://repl.it/BebC

I know I need to use a conditional, but I am not really sure where and on what to use it. If somebody could help me getting the desired result and explain a little bit why it works the way it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
h = {}
languages.each do |k, v| # oo or func
    v.each do |k1, v1| # ruby/python
        if h[k1]
            h[k1][:style] << k
        else
            h[k1] = {type: v1[:type], style: [k]}
        end
    end
end
```

It checks to see that `h` is defined, and if so, appends to its array. Otherwise it defines the entire hash with your type and a style array of size 1.

Comment: Also good naming would help greatly here, but he'll learn that, in time. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is too much unconditional overwriting going on in your code. Should be something like this instead:

```
  new_hash[k1] ||= {} # init to empty hash
  new_hash[k1][:type] = v1[:type]
  new_hash[k1][:style] ||= [] # make sure array exists
  new_hash[k1][:style] << k
```

Instead of replacing entire `new_hash[k1]`, you should change individual parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer (so please no upvotes). Rather, it is an extended comment to help you understand the code @Martin suggested. (I see you are new to SO and quite possibly to Ruby as well.) Salting code with `puts` statements, as I have done, is often quite helpful, even after you become experienced with the language.

```
languages = {
  :oo => {
    :ruby => {
      :type => "interpreted"
    },
    :javascript => {
      :type => "interpreted"
    }  
  },
  :functional => {
    :clojure => {
      :type => "compiled"
    },
    :javascript => {
      :type => "interpreted"
    } 
  }
}

h = {}
languages.each do |k, v| # oo or func
  puts "k=#{k}, v=#{v}"
  v.each do |k1, v1| # ruby/python
    puts "  k1=#{k1}, v1=#{v1}"
    if h[k1]
      puts "  h[#{k1}]=#{h[k1]} (truthy)"
      h[k1][:style] << k
      puts "  h after h[#{k1}][:style] << #{k}: #{h}"
    else
      puts "  h[#{k1}].nil?=true (falsy)"
      h[k1] = {type: v1[:type], style: [k]}
      puts "  h after h[#{k1}] = {type: v1[:type], style: #{k}}: #{h}"
    end
  end
end
```

prints:

```
k=oo, v={:ruby=>{:type=>"interpreted"}, :javascript=>{:type=>"interpreted"}}

  k1=ruby, v1={:type=>"interpreted"}
  h[ruby].nil?=true (falsy)
  h after h[ruby] = {type: v1[:type], :style: oo}:
    {:ruby=>{:type=>"interpreted", :style=>[:oo]}}

  k1=javascript, v1={:type=>"interpreted"}
  h[javascript].nil?=true (falsy)
  h after h[javascript] = {type: v1[:type], :style: oo}:
    {:ruby=>{:type=>"interpreted", :style=>[:oo]},
     :javascript=>{:type=>"interpreted", :style=>[:oo]}}

k=functional, v={:clojure=>{:type=>"compiled"}, :javascript=>{:type=>"interpreted"}}

  k1=clojure, v1={:type=>"compiled"}
  h[clojure].nil?=true (falsy)
  h after h[clojure] = {type: v1[:type], :style: functional}:
    {:ruby=>{:type=>"interpreted", :style=>[:oo]},
     :javascript=>{:type=>"interpreted", :style=>[:oo]},
     :clojure=>{:type=>"compiled", :style=>[:functional]}}

  k1=javascript, v1={:type=>"interpreted"}
  h[javascript]={:type=>"interpreted", :style=>[:oo]} (truthy)
  h after h[javascript][:style] << functional:
    {:ruby=>{:type=>"interpreted", :style=>[:oo]},
     :javascript=>{:type=>"interpreted", :style=>[:oo, :functional]},
     :clojure=>{:type=>"compiled", :style=>[:functional]}}
```

and returns:

```
  #=> {:oo       =>{:ruby=>{:type=>"interpreted"},
  #                 :javascript=>{:type=>"interpreted"}},
  #   :functional=>{:clojure=>{:type=>"compiled"},
  #                 :javascript=>{:type=>"interpreted"}}}
```

Comment: Thank you, Cary. This is incredibly valuable for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the hashes generated which is leading to the unexpected behavior you mentioned. The following piece of code does what you need. Its just a slightly modified version of your code.

```
def reformat_languages(languages)
  new_hash = {}
  languages.each do |k, v|
    v.each do |k1, v1|
      new_hash[k1] ||= v1 #ensures we do not overwrite the already generated language hash
      new_hash[k1][:style] ||= [] #protecting against re-initialization of the style array
      new_hash[k1][:style] << k     
    end
  end
  new_hash
end
```